# Finding eigenvalues and their eigenspaces:

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues and their eigenspaces:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     2 & -3 & 1 \\
>     1 & -2 & 1 \\
>     1 & -3 & 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}

The three eigenvalues I get are $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_1=1$, and $\lambda_2=1$.

Does this mean that that since two lambda's have the same value, I only have two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_1=1$? Or is there still 3: $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_1=1$, and $\lambda_2=1$

Because the answer I computed were:

from $\lambda_1=0$ one answer,

\begin{bmatrix}
   1\\ 
   1\\
   1\\
\end{bmatrix}

and from $\lambda_2=1$ I got two answers:

\begin{bmatrix}
   3\\ 
   1\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\ 
   0\\
   1\\
\end{bmatrix}

Is this three together correct? Also, how would I write this as an eigenspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. The matrix have an eigenvalue $\lambda =0$ of [algebraic multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity) $1$ and another eigenvalue $\lambda =1$ of algebraic multiplicity $2$. The fact that for for this last eigenvalue you find two distinct eigenvectors means that its [geometric multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces.2C_geometric_multiplicity.2C_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices) is also $2$.

---

this means that the eigenspace of $\lambda=1$ has dimension $2$ and can be expressed as the set of vectors of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3y-z\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=
y\begin{bmatrix}
3\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you! How would I write these results as an eigenspace though?

Comment: @BurstFlame You can write that the eigenspace of $\lambda=1$ is: $$E_1=<\begin{bmatrix}
   3\\ 
   1\\
   0\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\ 
   0\\
   1\\
\end{bmatrix}>$$ where $<\cdot>$ means "span of".

Comment: I've added to may answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful