# If you add 2 eigenvectors together does it equal the corresponding added eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If v1 is an eigenvector corresponding to λ1 and v2 is an eigen vector corresponding to λ2, is v1+v2 an eigenvector of A, corresponding to eigenvalue λ1+λ2? I'm so confused because I thought eigenvalues were distinct to the corresponding matrix. How can I prove this?

Comment: hi blake. This might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301877

Comment: The best you can say is $$A(\mathbf v_1 + \mathbf v_2) = A\mathbf v_1 + A\mathbf v_2 = \lambda_1\mathbf v_1 + \lambda_2\mathbf v_2.$$

Comment: If the sum of any two eigenvectors was an eigenvector, it would follow that _all_ vectors are eigenvectors.

Answer (score 4):

You have
$$A(v_1 + v_2) = Av_1 + Av_2 = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2$$
and you wonder if this implies
$$A(v_1 + v_2) = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)(v_1 + v_2)$$
This can only happen if
$$\lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)(v_1 + v_2)$$
This expression simplifies to $\lambda_1 v_2 + \lambda_2 v_1 = 0$, which implies that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are multiples of one another, which in turn implies $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 =: \lambda$. Therefore, $\lambda(v_2 + v_1) = 0$, so either $\lambda=0$ or $v_1 = -v_2$.

Comment: How did you get $v_1=-v_2$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri see the updated answer for the intermediate steps.

Comment: @MSE I made a mistake; you are correct.

Comment: When $\lambda_1 v_2 + \lambda_2 v_1 = 0$, that might mean $v_1$ is a multiple of $v_2$, or it might mean $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ and $v_i$ need not be a multiple of $v_j$. Same conclusion in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, and
$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$.
But $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is not an eigenvector.

Comment: How can I prove that it's not though

Comment: MSE's answer tells you exactly when it is true and when it is not.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.